# asp.net mvc3 how to pass ID variable but without in browser

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering how can I pass my primary-key int ID **myid** into a **.tolist** method that uses a **for each loop**

**VIEW**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)

{

@Html.ActionLink("View", "detail", new { id = item.myid})

@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "pictures")

}
```

**the .tolist  controller**

```
[Authorize]

public ActionResult mylist(list listings)
    {

var showlist = (from s in db.list where getid == s.RegistrationID select s).ToList();

        return View(showlist.ToList());

}
```

As you can see from above i do have the **[authorize]** notation on **mylist** which is were the foreach statement is on so people are logged on already. My question is were can I put the int **myid** in the **@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "pictures")** ?? I do not want to have it in the Browser since then users can easily put in different numbers and view other peoples pictures .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing the id in the url

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "pictures",new { @id=item.ID})
```

And in your pictures action method, you should check whether the current User is a logged (**Authentication**)  in user and he has proper permission to add picture (**Authorization**).

```
public ActionResult pictures(int id)
{
  //TO DO  : Check the user has sufficient permission to add pictures. 
  // The implementation of this checking is completely up to you.
  // If not authorized redirect to a view to show the "Not authorized" message

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just prevent people from looking at other people's pictures by checking if their user id matches the picture's owner's id?

You have to pass the id to the user, you can't avoid it.

Comment: I could try that but I was under the impression that if you show an INT variable onces people are logged in that it could lead to easier hacks . So basically if a user has more than 1 more profile using the same credentials then you must pass a variable to the browser?

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't show an INT variable and you would show a string of random characters or something like that. But what if the hacker guesses the string of characters? Your site would still be insecure. That is why you must perform a check inside your controller to make sure the user has permission to view the photo.

Answer (score 0):

That's not where you stop this kind of "hacking". In your controller or somewhere else, you do a check if the current authenticated user owns that photo and redirect him to a page that says "no picture found" - or something similar.